# Reload widget when pop from initialRoute

Tags: flutter

I just starting to learn flutter and want to implement login page.

So i check if i have token or not then decide if it is my `home route` or `login route` to be initialized as `initialRoute`, the problem is when flutter render `login route`, it also requesing API i declared on `home route` which is gonna return `empty list` because i dont have any token yet.

```
Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var status = prefs.getString('jwt') ?? "";
  if(status!="")
    runApp(HomeR(initialRoute: "/"));
  else
    runApp(HomeR(initialRoute: "/login"));
}


class HomeR extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/';
  HomeR({Key key, this.initialRoute}) : super(key: key);
  String initialRoute = "/";

   // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'blablabal',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'blablabla'),
      initialRoute: initialRoute,
      routes: {
        loginR.routeName: (context) => loginR(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and use `Navigator.pop(context)` from login button after authenticate first but my `home route` doesnt refresh itself and display nothing, since it is using `empty list` before.

How to tell `home route` to reload when i `pop from login route`?

Comment: I think it is better to set initialRoute to be something like `SplashRoute` and then in that screen check for token and navigate to correct route.

Comment: what is the different between splashroute and splashscreen?
i cant find about splash route?

Comment: No, I mean create a screen for loading app. and in that screen show loading and check for token.

Comment: and after that you push login page right?
and after that when you pop, the home route won't reload api

Comment: You have to set `home` to LoadingScreen and `initialRoute` to LoadingRoute, so home page is not in route stack at all.

Comment: If you need I can add code.

Comment: pls add it to answer section, im kind of blind, since this is my first project. thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `MaterialApp`:

```
MaterialApp(
      // no need for home
      title: 'blablabal',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => InitialApp(),
        loginR.routeName: (context) => loginR(),
      },
      initialRoute: '/',
),
```

and In InitialApp:

```
class InitialApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InitialAppState createState() => _InitialAppState();
}

class _InitialAppState extends State<InitialApp> {
  void loginLogic() async
  {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value){
      var status = value.getString('jwt') ?? "";
      if(status=='')
      {
         Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, loginR.routeName);
      }
      else //logged in
      {
         Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, LaporanList.routeName);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    loginLogic();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 1)can i just navigator.push on initstate?
2) is it fast enough to check shared preferenced before build  function start running?

Comment: 1) yes, 2) It show loading to user based on performance of their device,

Comment: hey,its working like what i want, but new problem appears here.
now since i navigator push from login page, my home route has back button on its appbar(topleft corner) i want it (home route) as base route without back button

Comment: Try `pushReplacement` instead of `push`.

Comment: i tried Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, LaporanList.routeName); too from ogin button but same result

Comment: ah, i solve it by putting pushReplacementNamed on initialApp.initState instead of login button

Comment: let me edit your answer and mark it as solved.
thankyou very much